# SSMS 2012 is not showing the tables of the system databases

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on my laptop connected to a SQL Server 2012. If I go in System Databases and then any of the 4 (master, model, msdb, tempdb) I don't have the Tables folder.

I'm quite sure it was there in SSMS 2008 R2. Why were the tables hidden? How can I make them visible?

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/773184/ssms-system-databases-node-does-not-show-tables

Comment: Well, OK. Make it an answer if you want the rep.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on SQL Server 2012 Standard SP1...

Comment: Are you using Management Studio or Management Studio Express? [As of SP1 Management Studio is now completely free](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) (so you'll have full SSMS functionality *and* you won't be hampered by this bug).

Comment: I have SP1 installed. If I run an installer (Standard Edition) and select add features it shows both Management Tools - Basic and Management Tools - Complete as already installed. Doesn't say Express anywhere in SSMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/773184/ssms-system-databases-node-does-not-show-tables) it will be fixed in the next major release of SQL Server.